# Five kids are sucked into video game and must retrieve a vial to save the creator's dying daughter

Tags: story-identification, books, video-games

The book starts with the main character (a boy) living, I think it's like a foster home or boarding school. He doesn't have much money, however he manages to get ahold of a video game. This video game has a competition running, where the 5 lucky winners get to trial the new game!

The main character wins the competition with 4 others, and it turns out that the video game has developed into a universe of its own! The game's creator has a daughter who is very sick and dying. To save the little girl, the 5 kids must go into the game and find a vial to make her better.

This was the plot for the FIRST book.

Also in the books:

- There was like a bit where the kids wanted to buy a map, and they couldn't figure out WHY the USED maps were more expensive than the new... then they realized that because on the game, a used map means its discovered more of the area.
- One of the children (a girl) takes the potion for looking beautiful
- Later in the OTHER BOOKS you find out the main character is like a Prince, and he is FROM the video game world

Details:

- There are I think 5-7 books in the series?
- The first book, has an olive green cover.
- They're a young adults/ children's book.

---

I read the books about 8 years ago. Publishing date I can't be sure... Though it can't be more than 15 years old.

It was  published in English. I read it in Australia, however I'm pretty sure it wasn't an Australian author.

Comment: Do you remember roughly how long ago you read them, and do you know if they were relatively new or already quite old books when you did so?

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I read the books about 8 years ago. The publishing date I can't be sure of, as my school library had just purchased them. I would give a MAX 10-15 year publishing possibility span.

Comment: What country and what language (if not English) did you read it in? (some works are published locally)

Comment: I think I read this one, but I can't remember what its called.   Where the game instructions are in Japanese? I remember that bit. ...Maybe a different book, after all.

Comment: It was published in English. I read it in Australia, however I'm pretty sure it was not an Australian author.

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't think the game instructions were in Japanese. However The main character had trouble reading them, as he wasn't the brightest/smartest guy.

Comment: This was a great movie when it was called "The Last Starfighter" ;)

Answer (score 12):

The name of the series is:  *The Karazan Quartet*
The first book is: *[The Serpents of Arakesh](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1219373.The_Serpents_of_Arakesh)*

[image: Book cover]

> Twelve-year-old orphan Adam Equinox is an unlikely hero - a lonely, misunderstood underacheiver who gets into fights, and whose spelling has to be seen to be believed. One day Adam enters the Quest Golden Opportunity Competition, with the ultimate prize of working with the reclusive software genius Quentin Quested, test-driving his latest top-secret breakthrough in computer game technology. Adam is unbelievably chosen to undergo the final selection process. At Quested Court, Adam enters a world he never dreamed existed. A world of kindly adults and potential friends, in which the boundaries between fantasy and reality start to become blurred. Only when Adam and his companions begin the gaming workshop does Quentin Quested reveal their real-life quest into the parallel world of Karazan, where the Serpents of Arakesh stand guard over the most precious prize of all.

Comment: If you return to the site, please accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark. :)

Comment: I was thinking this might be Space Demons ..https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Demons